# wp_ajax action is not running

Tags: ajax, hooks, actions

I'm writing a plugin.
I want to run the method get_my_option when someone pressing a button in the settings page of my wordpress plugin. The ajax call is made but the method never runs.

In the page I have the following code:

```
<div class="wrap">
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="my_js_function();"/>
</div>
<?php
wp_enqueue_script( 'function', plugins_url( '/js/synchandler.js',__FILE__),         array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script( 'function', 'my_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url(  'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );


function get_my_option()
{
    //do something
    die();
}

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_my_option", "get_my_option");
add_action("wp_ajax_get_my_option", "get_my_option");
?>
```

The added synchandler.js file:

```
function my_js_function() 
{
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: my_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({ action: 'get_my_option', affiliate: 'daisycon' }),
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("got this: " + response);
        }
    });
}
```

There is a response but that's a 0, so the javascript is added nicely but that's about it. I'm getting no errors in my log by running this. AjaxURL is added in the page (seems to be a common mistake).

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
var my_ajax_script = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/mywebsite.net\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
/* ]]> */
```

The button to trigger it all uses `onclick="my_js_function();` on the HTML `button`-tag.

As easy as it is, the method `get_my_option` doesn't get triggered by the ajax call. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Ehm... you need to close PHP with `?>` before adding JavaScript code and opening it again afterwards: `<?php`.

Comment: All javascript is in a separate file and added with wp_enqueue_script() so don't think that's a problem.

Comment: "The added synchandler.js file:" is the part I'm referring to. If this is the contents of the JavaScript file, then please show us where you call that function. I can't see it triggered anywhere.

Comment: It's inside a html input tag where I'm using an onclick event. Gonna try to put it in the question (is now written below the last codesnippet).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where are you calling add_action()? If it's in a place where you're already outputting HTML, it's too late, and that's probably a place that wont even be looked at during an AJAX request.

You should include that code in your theme's functions.php file, or as early as possible in a plugin.

Comment: As I have just seen that the OP seems to add the code in mid page, I have to double that. +1

Comment: Indeed it is. Adding the actions in the functions.php made it work. The problem I have with adding it in the functions.php in my theme folder is that I can't access the classes I need in the plugin folder. A solution is taking all code to the theme but it's kinda making the plugin useless.

Comment: Then just put it at the start of your plugin, outside of any other functions or classes and before you start outputting anything.

Comment: Adding it to the start of the plugin fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to put your functional code into the plugin, as a function (This depending on your way of developing your plugin.

I prefer to add the `add_action` calls to admin_init - It's called with admin-ajax.php too.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'function', plugins_url( '/js/synchandler.js',__FILE__),         array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script( 'function', 'my_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url(  'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );


function get_my_option()
{
    //do something
    die();
}
function add_ajax_actions() {
    add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_my_option", "get_my_option");
    add_action("wp_ajax_get_my_option", "get_my_option");
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_ajax_actions' );
```

I don't know if this is best practice - It's purely a personal preference, to avoid adding hooks to every page loaded - Only to admin pages.